# SAS: find quotation mark inside string

Tags: sas

I have quotation marks like " inside strings in various unknown places. I want to find/remove them.

I'm using `tranwrd()` function for other chars that I want to remove (like `+,-&` etc.).

Does anyone know how to do that?

Comment: Best thing to do is to use the `prxchange` function, which allows you to use Perl regular expressions in SAS. You can add the Perl and Regex tags to this, reformulate your question, and get even faster support on what regular expression would be required to remove these. I'm not the best at regex, but I have successfully used it in SAS with the various `prx` functions.

Comment: @Edit reviewers, please please please do not autoapprove adding code tags when they're wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `compress()` function.  First parameter is the string to modify, second parameter is the list of characters to remove.  I've put that list of characters in single quotes so that the `%` and `&` characters would not be picked up by the macro processor.

```
data want;
  tmp = '+blah -&blah'' "blah';
  want = compress(tmp,'+-&''"%');
  put tmp= want=;
run;
```

Alternatively the `compress()` function provides some nice ways to keep just certain characters.  In the below example I've told it to keep characters using the `k` modifier in the third argument.  The characters it will keep are the space character (which I've listed in the second argument) and  digits, the underscore character, and English letters (specified by the `n` modifier in the third argument).

```
data want;
  tmp = '+blah -&blah'' "blah';
  want = compress(tmp,' ','nk');
  put tmp= want=;
run;
```

Comment: `compress` documentation > https://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000212246.htm, with a list of all the third argument modifiers.

Comment: I think you buried the lede here...  the really important part is getting the quote character in the list (As you show but don't point out :) )  I separated that specifically into a separate answer, but +1 for your suggestion for compress for sure.

Comment: @Joe Good point.  When I read the question I focused on the `tranwrd()` part of it as being the problem because you would at least want to use `translate()` or even better `compress()`, but I can see how the real issue may be around quoting.

Answer (score 1):

If you're asking how you put a quote character inside a literal string, you have two options.

First, SAS allows both `'` and `"` to be used.  You can put one in the other.

```
data want;
  x = '"Dear me", she said.';
  y = compress(x,'"');
  put x= y=;
run;
```

Second, more useful if you either have macro variables or both kind of quotes, doubling the quote character escapes it.

```
data want;
  x = '"Dear me, please don''t do that", she said.';
  y = compress(x,'"''');
  put x= y=;
run;
```

Note in both places in the second example I put two `'` characters (the x assignment and the y compress).

`Compress` and `tranwrd` would both work the same way here (if you have a reason that `tranwrd` is superior for your use), as would any other SAS function or language element.

Second - for several functions, including `compress` but not `tranwrd` or `translate` - there is an optional parameter that lets you add all characters of a certain type.  `Compress` for some reason doesn't support `q` like some do, but it does support `p` for punctuation.  This may be desired, or may not.

```
data want;
  x = '"Dear me, please don''t do that", she said.';
  y = compress(x,,'p');
  put x= y=;
run;
```

Or, if you have a list of characters you *are* okay with, `k` lets you `keep` them:

```
data want;
  x = '"Dear me, please don''t do that", she said.';
  y = compress(x,'.,','kas');
  put x= y=;
run;
```

That keeps period, comma, a-z characters, and space characters, deletes all others.

Another interesting point:  `dequote()` will remove *pairs* of quotes, if you have them - ie, if you're just trying to remove quotes that are surrounding your character variables or something like that.